# Check existence of a key in an array with multiple keys in Tcl

Tags: arraylist, multidimensional-array, tcl

Is there a way to check a key existence, in an array with multiple keys? i.e...

```
    set test_arr(n1_temp,x_cell) 3
```

#As you can see that `test_arr` contains two keys named `n1_temp` and `x_cell`, now I am wondering if I can check the existence of a key named `n1_temp`

```
    if {[info exists test_arr(n1_temp)] } { ## not working 
    }
```

Please help.

-Regards,
Shikha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you can see that test_arr cotains two keys named n1_temp and x_cell

No, it has one key named `n1_temp,x_cell`.

Use a `dict` instead, which supports actual multi dimensional structures:

```
dict set test_dict n1_temp x_cell 3
if {[dict exists $test_dict n1_temp]} {
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array has one element, called `n1_temp,x_cell` with a comma in the name.

You can check for whether there is any element with `n1_temp` in the first part of the name by testing the length of the result list of `array names test_arr n1_temp,*` (that's a glob match). Be aware that this is an expensive operation in practice, as it has to do a linear scan of all the elements in the array.

```
if {[llength [array names test_arr n1_temp,*]]} {
    puts "There's an n1_temp,* element present"
}
```

Comment: FWIW, one of the things you need to think about when you design a data setup for any application in any language is what sort of questions you want to ask about the data. If getting all the things associated with a particular label is expected to be a common operation, it is therefore important to optimise how the data is structured to make that an easy operation to carry out.